# How to show sheet from separate NIB

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, interface-builder, cocoa-sheet

How do I put a window in a separate NIB, give it its own NSWindowController, make it slide out as a sheet?

(Is this a typical thing to do with sheets?)

I am trying to show a custom sheet (a window that slides down from the title bar of the parent window) from my main window.  What I'm trying to do is standard, I think, but I cannot find clear examples or explanations for how to do exactly what I want.

What I am trying to do:

1. My app delegate owns the main window, which has a button to open a "settings" sheet.

   The "settings" sheet:

   - is in a separate NIB.
   - has file owner set to class SettingsWindowController, which is subclass of NSWindowsController

   When user clicks "settings", I am trying to use Apple's [sample code][1]

```
- (void)showCustomSheet: (NSWindow *)window
// User has asked to see the custom display. Display it.
{
    if (!settingsSheet) 
    //Check the settingsSheet instance variable to make sure the custom sheet does not already exist.
        [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"SettingsSheet" owner: self];
        //BUT HOW DOES THIS MAKE settingsSheet NOT nil?

    [NSApp beginSheet: settingsSheet
            modalForWindow: window 
            modalDelegate: self 
            didEndSelector: @selector(didEndSheet:returnCode:contextInfo:) 
            contextInfo: nil]; 

    // Sheet is up here.

    // Return processing to the event loop
}
```

Please excuse the following simplistic and numerous questions:

- When I call, `loadNibName:owner:`, I don't want `owner` to be `self`, because that makes my app delegate the owner of the "MyCustomSheet" - that's what my `SettingsWindowsController` is supposed to be for. However, I don't know how make `SettingsWindowsController` the owner in this method.
- If my sheet has "Visible at launch" checked, then `loadNibName:owner:` immediately displays the window as a normal window, not as a sheet that slides out from the main window.
- If my sheet has "Visible at launch" not checked, then `beginSheet:modalForWindow:etc` causes "Modal session requires modal window".  I'm pretty sure this is because I made the Nib's owner `self` (as I mentioned already).
- In the sample code, I don't know how the Nib named @"SettingsSheet" is "associated" with the instance variable `settingsSheet` - but they apparently *are* related because the code checks first: `if (!settingsSheet)` (I've marked this with comment `//BUT HOW DOES THIS MAKE settingsSheet NOT nil?`)

Thanks for your patience in reading all this!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Create an instance of `SettingsWindowController`, use `initWithWindowNibName:`
2. You don't want it visible at launch.
3. See 1.
4. Your instance variables will be available to `SettingsWindowController`

Comment: THANK YOU!  This is exactly what I needed!  Would it have been too much to ask Apple to have done something this simple in their documentation? (Their sample code somehow doesn't seem to require the `initWitWindowNibName`.)

Comment: lol, yeah sometimes they have companion guides that get into this stuff, but if you are missing a couple of little pieces it can be hard to put together.

Comment: I tried to build up your example from scratch and was still getting the "Modal session requires modal window" error. I then checked everything bit-by-bit, line-by-line, in code and IB, against your example and couldn't see any difference. Finally, I put your 2 asserts in and saw that it failed on `assert (window)`. Do you know what makes this assertion pass or fail? I've obviously missed something somewhere

Comment: did you set the outlets for window in the IB?

Comment: also did you set the file owner's class in IB?

Comment: brilliant! Okay, it now works after I ctrl-dragged from the file's owner in the sheet's Nib to the window!

I'm definitely inexperienced with all this but it's not the first window in my real-world app... yet, I don't recall having to do this before...... is this something I just have to remember to do all the time, or only in these situations?

Comment: If I put a close button on the sheet, I call:

    -(IBAction)close:(id)sender {
        [[sender window] orderOut:nil];
        [NSApp endSheet:[sender window]];
    }

I don't know if this is correct, but it does dimiss the sheet.

Comment: to your previous question(and i thought i responded to it), you normally start with a project that has the outlets already set up, but if you are making your own, then you will have to. as for the second, I don't see any problem with that.

Comment: yes, it was your previous comment that made me find that small but critical step of setting the outlet. thanks again!

Comment: @GradyPlayer, if I turn breakpoint exception on in your project I will see:

`objc[36178]: EXCEPTIONS: throwing 0x1e4148fd8 (object 0x1e4144fd0, a NSException)
objc[36178]: EXCEPTIONS: searching through frame [ip=0x7fff868db540 sp=0x7fff5fbfcf60] for exception 0x1e4148fb8
objc[36178]: EXCEPTIONS: catch(NSException)
objc[36178]: EXCEPTIONS: unwinding through frame [ip=0x7fff868db540 sp=0x7fff5fbfcf60] for exception 0x1e4148fb8
objc[36178]: EXCEPTIONS: handling exception 0x1e4148fb8 at 0x7fff868db505
objc[36178]: EXCEPTIONS: finishing handler`

Do you know something about them? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @alexchernyy, I don't, but I will investigate next week if I think about it.

Comment: Any chance you could re-upload your example? Thanks!

Comment: @RotsiserMho I didn't know the link was bad, I will try